# How to access the data from data* attribute using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Scenario: When the user clicks on it, the data should be passed into `someFunction()`.

```html
<span id="someid" onClick={() => someFunction()} data-video-page="some data" class="dot" />`
```

I tried using `getAttributes()`, `querySelector()` methods until now to get the data from data attributes. But one of them are working, in fact they are returning none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `React.js` tag in your question, so I'll assume that this is for using `data-set` in React.js.

For React.js, this is how data-set can be used if you want to pass the data to some function on a click event. You can also visit the live demo here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fdqb5y?file=src/App.js)

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {

  // Your data is stored in event.currentTarget.dataset
  // Here we get the data by destructuring it
  // The name video-page need to change to videoPage for JS rules

  const { videoPage } = event.currentTarget.dataset;
  console.log(videoPage);

  // Result printed: "your data"
  // You can also run someFunction(videoPage) here
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <button data-video-page="your data" onClick={handleClick}>
      TEST
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data*` attribute can be accessed using the `getAttribute()` method.

Example 1:

```js
var data = document.getAttribute('data*');
```

Example 2:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('div');
var data = element.getAttribute('data');
```

Answer (score 0):

A working snippet

```js
const someFunction = console.log;

function App() {
    return (
        <span id="someid" 
          onClick={(e) => {
            const videoPage = event.target.dataset['videoPage'];
            someFunction(videoPage)
          }} 
          data-video-page="some data" 
          className="dot" 
        >
        click me
        </span>
     )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```