# How can I access 2 data attribute value using useRef hook?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

here I am confused about accessing 2 parameters on the endpoint.

```
/api/nad/buildingCount/:provinsi/:kota
```

Previously I was able to access 1 parameter using useRef, for example like this =

```
const provinsi = provinsiRef.current[index].dataset.value;
```

But when I tried for the 2 parameters, it was beyond my expectations.

This is my code, is there something wrong?. please for the solution, thank you

```
const handleKota = async (index) => {
    try {
      const provinsi = provinsiRef.current.dataset.value;
      const kota = provinsiRef.current[index].dataset.value;
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await getBuildingOLDallKecamatan(provinsi, kota);
      setDataKecamatan(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: useRef does not work as previously. useRef does not return value from an input tag.

Comment: so what solution can you give me? thanx in advance

Comment: r u using react-router-dom?

Comment: no sir. just useState and useRef.

Comment: My Full Code
https://pastebin.com/SU2szhZR
https://pastebin.com/XDwQhu2g

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you call `handleKota`, only one `index` is passed to the function, but the `index` in `provinsiRef.current[index]` and in `kotaRef.current[index]` are different, since these are 2 different `ref` array.

From your links to full code:

```
  const handleKota = async (index) => {
    try {
      const provinsi = provinsiRef.current[index].dataset.value;
      const kota = kotaRef.current[index].dataset.value;
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await getBuildingOLDallKecamatan(provinsi, kota);
      setDataKecamatan(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

As a result you might be getting mismatched `provinsi` and `kota`.

**Possible solutions**

1. [Data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) can carry a number of values. Therefore, you can give each `kota` item a value of `provinsi` they belong, such as `data-provinsi`. This way, you just need to access the `kota` ref, not both, to get everything needed for `handleKota`.
2. Instead of using `ref` to access data-set, use an approach that is not dependent on `index`. This does require some major refactor of existing code though. Perhaps check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398581/how-to-access-the-data-from-data-attribute-using-javascript) for a quick example about accessing data-set with the `event` object.

Comment: Sorry if this does not solve the problem, I could not test it here so just answering with my understanding in general. Perhaps consider another way of accessing data-set as well, I updated the answer and hopefully this could help a little at least as a reference. Thanks.

Comment: hello sir thanks for replying and helping me find a solution. i have revised my code like this https://pastebin.com/4XsSJLmB, but still failed to get the data. which appears empty array in the console. my endpoint fetch https://pastebin.com/egwQNtqD with 2 param path variable